# Hugo command hugo server -D issue

Tags: hugo

Please someone help me i don't understand the problem here.I'm new to hugo and this error just keeps on appearing when I try to create markdown file.[The error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Oo2Q.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Without having a link to the source code of the theme you're using, it's hard to tell. However, I found [giraffeacademy/ga-hugo-theme](https://github.com/giraffeacademy/ga-hugo-theme), which looks to be the same as what you're using (the line numbers seem to match).

It looks like the theme is outdated. It uses `.URL` in the list page template to try and link to the post that it's listing, but that isn't valid on the latest version of Hugo.

Changing `{{.URL}}` on line 14 in `theme/ga-hugo-theme-master/layouts/_default/list.html` to `{{.Permalink}}` should fix the issue.